# PHP for loop error !

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi here is my code, I cant figure out whats wrong ?

```
<?PHP
$my_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');

for (!$my_connection){
    die("Could not connect" . mysql_error());
}

echo "Conected sucessfully" . "<br>";

mysql_select_db('killer');

mysql_close($my_connection);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong?

Comment: Why are you using "for" instead of "if"?

Comment: What did you expect this to do…?

Comment: I think you mean `if` ... ? and you can also use that way:

`$my_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die(mysql_error());`

to save lines

Comment: first clue should be that this isn't a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `for` with `if`, that should do it

Answer (score 5):

revised code

```
<?php
    $my_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
    if (!$my_connection)
        die("Could not connect" . mysql_error());
    echo "Conected sucessfully <br/>";
    mysql_select_db('killer');
    mysql_close($my_connection);
    ?>
```

Comment: Dropping the if and just using `$my_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die("Could not connect" . mysql_error())` is (relatively) better.

Comment: @jhonP then how he display the message that connected successfully?

Comment: @JohnP: well, it's harder to switch to throw an exception which more often is the correct measure since it's recoverable. I wouldn't want the app to die just because it has a hard time connecting to a database.

Comment: Which is exactly why I added `(relatively)` in my comment :D